# plotting network - nodes too close together

Tags: plot, graph, igraph

I'm a novice but trying to make a graph of collaborations based on shared publications. I've got a plot that is getting there but the nodes are far too close to discern any of the edges. There are two nodes that aren't connected to any others but removing them doesn't seem to change the spread. Is there a way to spread these nodes out more?
Here's what I have so far:

```
 plot(net, edge.width=sqrt(links$weight),
 edge.arrow.size=0, edge.lty=1, mode=0, vertex.size=7,
 vertex.label.dist=2, vertex.label.cex=0.7)
```

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind I found the layout options

Comment: For times like this, either post a detailed answer that is reproducible (your question clearly is not) or just delete the question. This is not an answer.